# How to use datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetime, datepicker, datetimepicker

I want to have a calndar with time into my form.
I tried to do this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
        });


  <div id="date" class="datetimepicker input-append">
        <input id="extra2" name="extra2" type="text" class="input-block-level " />
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" ></i>
             </span>
    </div>
```

But I am not able to set and see the time. I just only to select the data.

Comment: which plugin you are using ?

Comment: should have document about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it just displays a text input field. 
Try this

```
<div id="date" class="datetimepicker input-append">
        <input id="extra2" name="extra2" type="datetime-local" class="input-block-level " />
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" ></i>
             </span>
    </div>
```

I hope that is what you are looking for. However this will not work in firefox.